# how to create a timer that displays an image for a second c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I've been writing a program in c# using windows form(WPF), and I've been stuck on this problem. I'm   trying to create a function that will displays an image for a few seconds. This function has to be able to be called from an outside function.

Comment: Show the image, start a timer that when fires hides the image?

Comment: *"I've been writing a program in c#"* can we see it please?

Comment: WPF does not have form

Comment: i'm not doing it atm but so you're informed as to why you are beeing downvoted: Your question shows no effort in trying this yourself and it's trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method should be fairly trivial. When called it would show your image (it's visibility could be false by default). The method could then start a timer, with an interval of the required number of seconds. In the timers elapsed callback you could simply set the images visibility to false.

```
DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);   //fire after 3 seconds

...

private void ShowMyImage()
{
    // logic to show your image
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // logic to hide your image
    dispatcherTimer.Stop();
}
```